# Perl flock on Linux: what if many processes wait to open a locked file?

Tags: linux, perl, locking

What happens if many processes are waiting to open an exclusively locked file, when it is released?

I would expect only one of the processes which required the open to succeed to open the file again, but it doesn't seem to be the case...

I did read the documentation of linux `flock` system call (and also Perl's `flock()` function), but I can't find any coverage of that use case...

This is my use case in detail:
some CGI perl processes call one central service on the LAN, which is quite heavy and slow, and performs better if it's called by one client at a time. CGI requests are potentially many (say 50 ~ 60) and concurrent, so I use the `flock` machinery to behave as a *semaphore* for the CGI processes to wait before calling the central service, one at a time.

This is the (simplified) code I use to implement the semaphore:

```
open($LOCK, "+>" . "/tmp/semaphore.lock") or die("Can't open semaphore ($!)");
flock($LOCK, LOCK_EX) or die ("Can't lock semaphore ($!)");

# <CALL THE SLOW SERVICE>

flock($LOCK, LOCK_UN) or die("Can't unlock semaphore ($!)");
close($LOCK);
```

The flow I'd expect is:

```
CGI process A opens semaphore
CGI process A locks semaphore
CGI process A calls service
CGI process B opens semaphore
CGI process C opens semaphore
CGI process D opens semaphore
CGI process A unlocks semaphore
CGI process B locks semaphore
CGI process B calls service
CGI process B unlocks semaphore
CGI process C locks semaphore
...
```

But, the flow I observe is:

```
CGI process A opens semaphore
CGI process A locks semaphore
CGI process A calls service
CGI process B opens semaphore
CGI process C opens semaphore
CGI process D opens semaphore
CGI process A unlocks semaphore
CGI process B locks semaphore
CGI process B calls service
CGI process C locks semaphore   (!)
CGI process C calls service     (!)
CGI process D locks semaphore   (!)
CGI process D calls service     (!)
CGI process B unlocks semaphore
...
```

The answer (if possible) should prioritize a solution with the least possible modifications to current code, since it is in production since quite a long time, so: the fewer changes, the better... :-)

Comment: I can't replicate the behaviour. Sometimes, a process locks between unlock and close of another process, but that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one process can hold an exclusive lock at any given time.

As such, one of the following should be true for you:

- The file you are locking is located on an NFS devices. `flock` doesn't support these.
- The calls to `flock` you describe occurred in the same process. `flock` can't be used to exclude threads of the same process.
- The lock was released. Keep in mind the unlock could have happened in a forked process.